# How do I feed responses from a multilingual Microsoft Form (English/French) into a single SharePoint list using Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, form, automation

I am having a hard time trying to feed responses from a multilingual Microsoft Form into a single SharePoint list using Power Automate.

How would I approach this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using a basic flow of the following and it seemed to work.
Any errors that you are getting?

**Flow:**

[image]

**SharePoint list:**

[image]

Comment: There were no errors, when I submitted a french form submission it doesnt translate the text it keeps it as English. Not sure how it worked for you.

Comment: Have you enable multilingual on your SharePoint site? https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-multiple-languages-on-a-sharepoint-site/